# Find a polynomial $P_n$ such that the closed disk of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ is not contained in $P_n(\mathbb{D})$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I try to solve the following problem:

> Let $\mathbb D=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z| < 1\}$. For an integer $n\geq 1$, find a polynomial of degree $n$
>   $$P_n(z)=z+a_2z^2+\cdots +a_nz^n$$ such that the closed disk of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ is not contained in $P_n(\mathbb{D})$.

---

My attempt:

To solve this, I want to directly find a polynomial such that $P_n(\mathbb{D})$ is strictly contained in a circle of radius $\frac{1}{n}$. And if $|z|<1$, we have 
$$|P_n(z)|=|z+a_2z^2+\cdots +a_nz^n|\leq |z|+|a_2z^2|+\cdots +|a_nz^n|<1+a_2+\cdots a_n$$
Though it looks hopeless to get rid of the term ''$1+\cdots$'' so it cannot be less than $\frac{1}{n}$ by some coarse estimates...

I also try to consider the polynomial 
$$f(z)=z-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)z^n$$

why I consider this is its image has some symmetric property (preserved after rotation by $\frac{\pi}{n-1}$). Due to this, we can reduce all disk to some disk ''near'' the real line.

---

Note that we need a normalized polynomial, namely, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. In that sense, some classic tricks, such as scaling and translation, are not allowed anymore.

Comment: What does that even mean? Why do you expect us to know what these symobls mean?

Comment: @zhw. I am sorry, which symbols are ambiguous?

Comment: What does 'belonging' mean? Do you want them to be disjunct or such that $D_{\frac{1}{n}}$ is not entirely contained in $P(\mathbb{D})$?

Comment: @GuidoA. Oh, I see. I will fix.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I see what you mean now.

Comment: I've edited my post to cover both cases Edit: I think I made a mistake, deleting it for now

Comment: Isn't it obviously false for $n=1$? I mean $P_1(z)=z$ and $P_1(\mathbb{D})=\mathbb{D}$, i.e. not only it contains the disc of radius 1 but in fact, they're equal.

Comment: @stressed-out Actually, we require the closed disk of radius 1.

Comment: @LeoGardon: Yes, but looking at the wording of the problem again, it says that $\mathbb{D}$ (the closed disc of radius $1$) should not be contained in $P_1(\mathbb{D})=\mathbb{D}$. Isn't that false? or am I missing something?

Comment: It means the closed disk should not be contained in the image of the open disk.

Comment: @stressed-out one of the disk is closed and the other is open. Just like what Robert said.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Then $\mathbb{D}$ is the open disk here? I have usually seen that notation used to refer to the closed unit disc. In fact, disk is usually considered closed, while the open disk is usually called a ball and denoted by $B$ instead of $D$.

Comment: @stressed-out Notations differ.  $\mathbb D$ or $D$ for the open unit disk is pretty common in complex analysis. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $P_n(z) = \frac{1 - (1-z)^n}{n}$.  Note that $P_n(z) = 1/n$ only for $z=1$ (which is not in the open unit disk).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I think your hint only can indicate that it cannot contain a closed disk whose center is $O$. But what if the circles centered at some other positions?

Comment: According to Landau's theorem, there is a positive constant $L$ such that $P_n(\mathbb D)$ always contains a disk of radius $L$.

Comment: No. Bloch’s Theorem said that we have a disk in the domain, not the image. Also, I think “closed” is not satisfied, which actually doesn’t matter.

Comment: Actually [Landau's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem_(complex_variables)#Landau.27s_theorem), although Conway calls it Bloch's theorem.

Comment: Oh! I see! I misunderstood what it asks.